# How can I center 2 or more widgets(Screen) in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I want to center 2 Buttons and Text in the center of the screen.
I want something like that,
[image]

I am using this code :

```
body: Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 40.0,
                  fontFamily: 'Hero',
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    _counter += 1;
                  });
                },
                child: Text('Increment')),
            ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    _counter -= 1;
                  });
                },
                child: Text('Decrement'))
          ],
        ),
      ],
    ),
```

I am now using Both Row and Column widget and setting MainAxisAlignment to Center. I guess this is not an efficient way to do this.

I tried this one code as shown on other stackoverflow Question (using CrossAxisAlignment)

```
body: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        Text(
          '$_counter',
          style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 40.0,
              fontFamily: 'Hero',
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        ),
        ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                _counter += 1;
              });
            },
            child: Text('Increment')),
        ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                _counter -= 1;
              });
            },
            child: Text('Decrement'))
      ],
    ),
```

But this code is not working the way I want! It is showing me something like this.
[image]

Any solution ?
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wrap your column with `Center`.

```dart
body:Center(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
```

Comment: Thanks buddy, When I earlier tried wrapping the column with center I missed the crossAxisAlignment param.

Comment: Glad to help you out. also you can check https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout

Answer (score 2):

Try to add your Column Widget Inside Center refer below code hope its help to you see below image its the center of the mobile screen:

```
   Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Text(
              'Your Text',
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 40.0,
                  fontFamily: 'Hero',
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              child: Text('Increment'),
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              child: Text('Decrement'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

Your Output Screen -> [image]

Comment: Yeah buddy, I guess you are missing a crossAxisAlignment param in Column. I tried the same approach as yours. Adding the crossAxisAlignment fixed my problem.